# importing python netmiko library in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am beginer to robotframework and netmiko.
I tried to print out the whoami using netmiko in python.

```
import netmiko

mydevice = {
'device_type': 'linux',
'ip': '127.0.0.1',
'username': 'gns3',
'password': 'gns3',
'verbose':True
}

conn = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**mydevice)
cmd = 'whoami\n'
output = conn.send_command(cmd)

def display_cmd():
    print(conn.find_prompt() + cmd + output + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (display_cmd())
```

It looks working.

```
gns3@gns3vm:~/project$ python netmiko_test.py
SSH connection established to 127.0.0.1:22
Interactive SSH session established
gns3@gns3vm:~$whoami
gns3

None
```

Then I tried to make quick simple robot file here.

```
*** Settings ***
Library         netmiko_test.py

*** Test Case ***
whoami      display whoami

*** Keywords ***
display whoami
    ${result}  display cmd
    Log To Console     ${result}
```

I expected the same python output would be in the log.html with all PASS but the following error comes.

```
gns3@gns3vm:~/project$ robot rf_test.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/gns3/project/rf_test.robot': Importing test library '/home/gns3/project/netmiko_test.py' failed: SSHException: No existing session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gns3/project/netmiko_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    conn = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**mydevice)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 131, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 532, in establish_connection
    self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 391, in connect
    server_key = t.get_remote_server_key()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 718, in get_remote_server_key
    raise SSHException('No existing session')
PYTHONPATH:
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/lib/python2.7
  /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
==============================================================================
Rf Test
==============================================================================
whoami                                                                | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'display cmd' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rf Test                                                               | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /home/gns3/project/output.xml
Log:     /home/gns3/project/log.html
Report:  /home/gns3/project/report.html
```

Could you advise me where is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the name of your Python file?

Comment: That is the same in the code, "netmiko_test.py"

Answer (score 0):

If the file you posted is the same file you run, then I guess you're not using the correct function to print to the console. That said, as this is a rather small example I formatted as a library for you. As I don't have the option to run `Netmiko` I was unable to test is properly.

```
import netmiko

class NetmikoLibrary(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def display_cmd(self, cmd = 'whoami\n'):
        '''
            This is my Netmiko keyword to execute a command.
        '''
        mydevice = {
        'device_type': 'linux',
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'username': 'gns3',
        'password': 'gns3',
        'verbose':True
        }

        conn = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**mydevice)

        output = conn.send_command(cmd)
        return output
```

This does mean that you can to load your library slightly different: `Library         NetmikoLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kootstra. I didn't know that the all variables must be in executed command(display_cmd), but thought that all contents can be addressed  even though located outside of display_cmd.

It works now after re-locate variables inside of display_cmd.

```
import netmiko

def display_cmd():
    mydevice = {
    'device_type': 'linux',
    'ip': '127.0.0.1',
    'username': 'gns3',
    'password': 'gns3',
    'verbose':True
    }

    conn = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**mydevice)
    cmd = 'whoami\n'
    output = conn.send_command(cmd)

    return (conn.find_prompt() + cmd + output + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (display_cmd())
```

Result like this, all passed.

```
gns3@gns3vm:~/project$ robot rf_test.robot
==============================================================================
Rf Test
==============================================================================
whoami                                                                gns3@gns3vm:~$whoami
gns3

whoami                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rf Test                                                               | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /home/gns3/project/output.xml
Log:     /home/gns3/project/log.html
Report:  /home/gns3/project/report.html
```

Thank you.